# Is there a way to add REGEX FLAGS to patterns in Telethon?

Tags: telethon

In Telethon you can define [patterns](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html?highlight=pattern#newmessage) like this:
`@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i).*Hello'))`

But sometimes you need to add some regex flags (re.MULTILINE).
How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `'(?im).*Hello'`?

(I don't know Telethon library, from Java ecosystem I know there are [inline equivalents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) for regex flags exactly as you already used in `(?i)` case.)